# PHP getimagesize with ampersand in string creates errors

Tags: php, image, ampersand, getimagesize

I'm using the getimagesize function in PHP, and the path string contains an ampersand, which otherwise is fine. 
The page gives me errors where getimagesize() is called. Looking at the source code, though, I see the ampersand is being passed through as & rather than just &
I presume this is causing errors because PHP doesn't need to convert it to the html tag in order to find the path, right?

Here is the error:

> Warning: getimagesize(image.php?name=username&pic=picture) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Please post, your code. Looks like you are passing an invalid argument to getimagesize.

Comment: like what? I'd paste it but it's on my other machine. It's just a string that's a URL.
$location = "image.php?name=username&pic=picture";
$size = getimagesize($location);

Answer (score 1):

If you want getimagesize to fetch the image from a remote server, by sending an HTTP request and downloading it, you need to use an absolute URL *(starting with `http://domainname.ext/...`)*

For example, this portion of code :

```
$url = 'http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif?test=glop&blah=huhu';
$data = getimagesize($url);
var_dump($data);
```

Gives me :

```
array
  0 => int 120
  1 => int 67
  2 => int 1
  3 => string 'width="120" height="67"' (length=23)
  'bits' => int 7
  'channels' => int 3
  'mime' => string 'image/gif' (length=9)
```

If you don't want to fetch a remote image, then, you need to specify the path to an image that exists on the same machine than the one where PHP runs.

And, in your case, I doubt that you have a physical file called `'image.php?name=username&pic=picture'`.

Comment: It's not that. I have the same problem and I'm using absolute path. The errorlog shows something like this:  PHP Warning:  getimagesize(https://graph.facebook.com/1234/picture?type=normal&amp;access_token=SECRETTOKENSUPERDUPER) [<a href='function.getimagesize'>function.getimagesize</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!